# Deactivate scrolling in parentwidget while mouse is in childwidget in python and PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I create a widget which is to big to show complete on the screen, so i put it in a scrollbox.
In this widget is a listwidget which is scrollable as well.
What can i do to disable scrollfunction in the outer widget, if the mouse is in the listwidget, and enable the scrollingfunction if i move the mouse out of the listwidget?
I tried something out with an eventFilter, but nothing works.

**scroll.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 500)
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 500))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -158, 463, 915))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 200))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.listWidget.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.frame_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 200))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 255, 255);")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2)
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.frame_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 200))
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 255);")
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_3)
        self.frame_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.frame_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 200))
        self.frame_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 170, 127);")
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName("frame_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_4)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Item 1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Item 2"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Item 3"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Item 4"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Item 5"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Item 6"))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

with the eventFilter i tried something like this.
**This is from my code.** NOT FROM THE EXAMPLE ABOVE

```
#...
self.stack.listWidget_2.installEventFilter(self)
#...
#...
```

and

```
def eventFilter(self, source, event):
    if source is self.listwidget_2 and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
        self.wheelEvent = lambda event: None
    return super(mainwindow, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

I also tried with other event.types but nothing works like i wanne to have.

Comment: How did you try the event filter? Note that what you're showing is just a "helper form class", it's not an actual QWidget, it's created by the pyuic tool and it's ***NOT*** intended to be modified, so if you tried to implement `eventFilter` there it would never work. To understand how to properly use those pyuic files, read more on the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) (specifically, the third approach, using multiple-inheritance).

Comment: This code is just an example to show the problem. I can't post the original code but the behavior ist the same. When I scroll in the inside scrollbox and come to the end, automatically the mainwindow scrolls down. But I don't want this. I just want to allow to scroll the parent if the mouse is out of the inner Listwidget

Comment: We are aware of the "problem", and that's the expected behavior. Please understand that it's more useful to you (as to others reading your question in the future) if you show us what you actually tried. The purpose of SO is not only to give solutions, but also to provide means to understand where the problem *actually* is. Since this is the expected behavior and your attempt to override didn't work, you should show us what you tried in order to provide *good* answers.

Comment: i know this is the expected behavior, but i don't like it :-) i thought maybe there is an easy solution for that. i thing i found something to do this in C++ but this is not my language. I hopped someone has a quick solution.

Comment: @Robert You need to filter on the wheel-events of the list-widget viewport, then accept any events that you don't want to propagate to the parent, and return true. The relevant events will occur when `event.angleDelta().y()` is negative and the slider-position equals the scroll-maximum (and *vice versa*).

Comment: @ekhumoro That sounds difficult to me. My english is not the best. Do you mean, that i should deactivate the event of the mainwidget, if the scroll_max position of the listwidget is reached and not by hovering over it?

Comment: @Robert No, call `event.accept()` and `return True` if a  list-widget wheel-event occurs when its slider is at the top (scroll-minimum) or the bottom (scroll-maximum). Forget about hovering, it's totally irrelevant. This is very simple to implement (only about 10 lines of code). It's important that the event-filter is set on the *viewport*: i.e. `self.listWidget.viewport().installEventFilter(self)`.

Comment: Puuhh. This is to hard for me. I'm not sure what exactly I have to accept(), or what this is done. Also I'm not sure what I should set to True. If you have a short code example I would be grateful.